# trying to read from a RFID RDM6300 on a raspberry pi but it gets stucked

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, rfid

doing this tutorial https://behindthesciences.com/electronics/raspberry-pi-rfid-tag-reader/ the code doesn´t return anything and it gets stucked.

If I comment out the line: read_byte = PortRF.read(), the while works, otherwise it gets stucked and doesn´t read anything.

also, is there a way to detect anything on those pins and see if the RFID RDM6300 is working ?

the code is the following

```
import time
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
#GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)


Tag1 = str('1800387799CE')
#GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.output(23,False)
#GPIO.output(24,False)
testVar = 0
PortRF = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600)
#PortRF = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0',9600)
print 'PortRF ' 
print PortRF
while True:
    print testVar
    testVar = testVar + 1
    #GPIO.cleanup()
    print 'en el while' 
    ID = ""
    try:
        print 'en el try' 
        read_byte = PortRF.read()
        pass
        print 'LECTURA ' + read_byte
        read_byte = "\x03"
    except ValueError as identifier :
        print 'No puede leer: ' + identifier
    if read_byte=="\x02":
        for Counter in range(12):
            read_byte=PortRF.read()
            ID = ID + str(read_byte)
            print hex(ord( read_byte))
        print ID
        if ID == Tag1:
            print "matched"
            #GPIO.output(23,True)
            #GPIO.output(24,False)
            time.sleep(5)
            #GPIO.output(23,False)
        else:
            #GPIO.output(23,False)
            print "Access Denied"
            #GPIO.output(24,True)
            time.sleep(5)
            #GPIO.output(24,False)  
GPIO.cleanup() # this ensures a clean exit
```

Comment: How do you connect the RDM6300 to the RPi? Pin-by-Pin or a picture will be helpful

Comment: What is the output of `print 'LECTURA ' + read_byte`? Why do you assign a value to `read_byte` at `read_byte ="\x03"`?